# data type unit8 in python

Tags: python, pandas, types, model

I converted the variable BRANCH to some dummy variables from B2 to B19. But the datatype of these dummy variables becomes unit8 which is a string, so I cannot scale the data and put them to my model since these variables are not numerical. How to convert unit8 to int?

## Make dummies

dummy = pd.get_dummies(df['BRANCH'], drop_first=True) 
dummy

## Join the dataframe with dummies to the original dataframe

new_df = pd.concat([df,dummy], axis=1)
new_df

## Drop BRANCH

new_df.drop(['BRANCH'], axis=1, inplace = True)
new_df

## Check data type

new_df.info()

47  B10      32264 non-null  uint8
 48  B11      32264 non-null  uint8
 49  B12      32264 non-null  uint8
 50  B13      32264 non-null  uint8
 51  B14      32264 non-null  uint8
 52  B15      32264 non-null  uint8
 53  B16      32264 non-null  uint8
 54  B17      32264 non-null  uint8
 55  B18      32264 non-null  uint8
 56  B19      32264 non-null  uint8
 57  B2       32264 non-null  uint8
 58  B3       32264 non-null  uint8
 59  B4       32264 non-null  uint8
 60  B5       32264 non-null  uint8
 61  B6       32264 non-null  uint8
 62  B7       32264 non-null  uint8
 63  B8       32264 non-null  uint8
 64  B9       32264 non-null  uint8

Comment: `uint8` is an integer type, not a string (you are also misspelling it as `unit8`, which is not how it appears in your example)

Comment: Thank you! There is a value error after I scale the data. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'B14'. Does it mean I should convert these dummy variables to float?

Comment: Yes, it is trying to convert `'B14'` to a floating point number, which it can't do. They have to be in a format which is convertible to a float, like `'1.2'` or `'1.02e3'` which is valid scientific notation.